# Rewire Ball-Type Mouse

Tags: pcb, soldering, mouse

Im trying to Frankenstein a trackball connection through a mouse controller exactly like this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC7jhdAMwiw

In short, Im using a ball-type-mouse PCB to connect to a trackball which had a proprietary internal connection so I can then connect it to a computer.

After much grief, I did successfully get the X/Y movement to work.

As viewed on the screen -- The X-axis works great. The Y-Axis responsiveness is odd. Shorter/Slower movements dont always register.

I swapped the X/Y connections, and the Y-Axis (as viewed on the screen) continued to be less-responsive - even though the X of the trackball was now connected to it. To me, the somewhat isolates the issue to the Y-axis of the PCB.

I resoldered the Y connections a couple times, always the same result.

The one peice of extra info I do have is, that the Y-Axis does not work unless I connect the X-Axis. I don't know if this is by design or something that Im causing and is just another symptom of why the Y-Axis is acting odd.

Any thoughts to help diagnose this would be amazing...

**UPDATE:**

thank you for the responses. I swapped out the PCB for a Dell-Ball mouse. Once I figured out the wire layout (very similar to the MS-Mouse) both X/Y axis work and are very responsive.

I must have either cross soldered something, or just F'd the board up.

Working as expected, with great resolution.

Comment: these connections are analog but translate to binary logic levels of current and voltage with the ball rotating a wheel to interrupt the IR light.  Inspect this aspect of the rubber rotating or slipping from ball to rotor. Clean with Isoprop.  Both sensors share supply and ground.

Comment: Truly an X-Y problem ;-)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  thanks -- the issue appears to be after the ball/cog/IR -- as when I take the two AXIS and flip them its always the axis that is connected to the Y axis on the PCB of the mouse.

Comment: ok yes Y gain then must be in code is weird or normal for that game.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. The Y axis works fine when attached to the Xaxis of the mouse PCB ... its the mouse Y PCB that seems to be the issue. And since its a standard mouse. I wouldnt think its a gain issue? This behaviour happens when used a mouse in windows

Comment: Could light be leaking into the Y-axis detector, rendering it less reliable?

Comment: I thought this as well when I was testing it unmounted .. but even after the case was put on it was still acting wonk -- I swapped for a completely different mouse/pcb (Dell) and it works amazingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the schematic of the mouse you are using AND the inputs you expect to have to process.

Here is a typical schematic for X/Y and you are dealing with an A/B quadrature signal:

[image]

Source was this [datasheet](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=e21f826dc53dd7e01c4093192c79557bc7d3f8), but it is typical for many of the simple ball mouse implementations. Notice that the X/Y and Z sensing is using the SAME inputs for processing and the LEDs for X/Y and Z are switched which creates quite some complexity.

If you pick up the LEDs as shown in the video you are likely to have trouble. I'd suggest if you want to just use the sensors you cut the tracks to the LEDs so you can drive them separately ....or if the LEDs are in series isolate the two LEDs and the series resistor and power from 5V.

As already pointed out the signals are analog and need to be processed by a Schmidt trigger input to clean them up.

Comment: Thanks -- that takes my feeble mech-eng brain for a spin. Ive updated the original ask, as swapping out for a different mouse PCB has fixed the issue. Im going to hang my hat on the first board being F'd up by my solder skills

Comment: @cgmckeever I doubt your first board is messed up. I'd suggest It will be using a circuit much like that show above. Could it be that the second board you chose did not have a wheel sensor (in addition to the mouse X/Y) and so was less complex?

Comment: actually, the new board has (well had) the third wheel. Im not sure Im tracking though, as the same set-up (to my knowledge) with the same mouse/pcb and trackball as that video had some poor Y-Axis issues (regardless if I attached the X or Y trackball to it) ... Im just glad its working!!!